# Cache repliation with ehcache in Tomcat cluster

Tags: java, spring, jakarta-ee, caching, ehcache

I have the following ehcache configs for 3 different tomcat instances.

My assumption is, that in each ehcache, we should define all the other nodes as provider and this current node as listener.

Should we define all of our caches in each ehcache.xml? and if yes, should we also add these names to the RMI addresses?
I defined the ehcaches like this. The replication for two of the caches work fine, but for other two caches it does not work(activityCache and classificationCache). Of course it should depend one their implementations, but at this time, i would like to make sure that the ehcache configs are correct.

```
<ehcache xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="ehcache.xsd">

 <cache name="activityCache"
           maxElementsInMemory="30"
           maxElementsOnDisk="100000"
           eternal="true"
           overflowToDisk="true"
           diskPersistent="true"
           diskSpoolBufferSizeMB="20"
           timeToIdleSeconds="50"
           timeToLiveSeconds="5"
           memoryStoreEvictionPolicy="LFU">

            <bootstrapCacheLoaderFactory class = "net.sf.ehcache.distribution.RMIBootstrapCacheLoaderFactory" properties = "bootstrapAsynchronously=false, maximumChunkSizeBytes=5000000"/>

            <cacheEventListenerFactory class = "net.sf.ehcache.distribution.RMICacheReplicatorFactory" properties="replicateAsynchronously=true, asynchronousReplicationIntervalMillis=100"/>

           </cache>

         <cache name="featureCache"
           maxElementsInMemory="30"
           maxElementsOnDisk="100000"
           eternal="true"
           overflowToDisk="true"
           diskPersistent="true"
           diskSpoolBufferSizeMB="20"
           timeToIdleSeconds="50"
           timeToLiveSeconds="5"
           memoryStoreEvictionPolicy="LFU">            

            <bootstrapCacheLoaderFactory class = "net.sf.ehcache.distribution.RMIBootstrapCacheLoaderFactory" properties = "bootstrapAsynchronously=false, maximumChunkSizeBytes=5000000"/>

            <cacheEventListenerFactory class = "net.sf.ehcache.distribution.RMICacheReplicatorFactory" properties="replicateAsynchronously=true, asynchronousReplicationIntervalMillis=100"/>

           </cache> 

        <cache name="classificationCache"
           maxElementsInMemory="30"
           maxElementsOnDisk="100000"
           eternal="true"
           overflowToDisk="true"
           diskPersistent="true"
           diskSpoolBufferSizeMB="20"
           timeToIdleSeconds="50"
           timeToLiveSeconds="5"
           memoryStoreEvictionPolicy="LFU">    

            <bootstrapCacheLoaderFactory class = "net.sf.ehcache.distribution.RMIBootstrapCacheLoaderFactory" properties = "bootstrapAsynchronously=false, maximumChunkSizeBytes=5000000"/>

            <cacheEventListenerFactory class = "net.sf.ehcache.distribution.RMICacheReplicatorFactory" properties="replicateAsynchronously=true, asynchronousReplicationIntervalMillis=100"/>

           </cache>

    <cache name="userGroupCache"
           maxElementsInMemory="30"
           maxElementsOnDisk="100000"
           eternal="true"
           overflowToDisk="true"
           diskPersistent="true"
           diskSpoolBufferSizeMB="20"
           timeToIdleSeconds="50"
           timeToLiveSeconds="5"
           memoryStoreEvictionPolicy="LFU">

            <bootstrapCacheLoaderFactory class = "net.sf.ehcache.distribution.RMIBootstrapCacheLoaderFactory" properties = "bootstrapAsynchronously=false, maximumChunkSizeBytes=5000000"/>

            <cacheEventListenerFactory class = "net.sf.ehcache.distribution.RMICacheReplicatorFactory" properties="replicateAsynchronously=true, asynchronousReplicationIntervalMillis=100"/>

           </cache>                

 <cacheManagerPeerProviderFactory class = "net.sf.ehcache.distribution.RMICacheManagerPeerProviderFactory" properties = "peerDiscovery=manual, rmiUrls=//localhost:40002/activityCache|//localhost:40002/userGroupCache|//localhost:40002/featureCache|//localhost:40002/classificationCache//localhost:40003/activityCache|//localhost:40003/userGroupCache|//localhost:40003/featureCache|//localhost:40003/classificationCache"/>

<cacheManagerPeerListenerFactory class = "net.sf.ehcache.distribution.RMICacheManagerPeerListenerFactory" properties = "hostName=localhost, port=40001, socketTimeoutMillis=2000"/>

</ehcache>
```

Here are also the definitions of caches and cahchSevices:

```
     <bean id="featureCache" parent="abstractOptionalCache">
        <property name="maxElementsInMemory" value="${cache.feature.maxMemoryElements}"/>
        <property name="maxElementsOnDisk" value="${cache.feature.maxDiskElements}"/> 
        <property name="overflowToDisk" value="${cache.feature.useDisk}"/>
      </bean>

      <bean id="featureCacheService" parent="abstractService" class="com.service.business.cache.impl.ehcache.EHcacheFeatureCacheService">
        <property name="cache"  ref="featureCache"/>
        <property name="enabled" value="${cache.feature.enable}"/>
      </bean> 

      <bean id="activityCache" parent="abstractMandatoryCache">
        <property name="cacheManager" ref="cacheManager"/>
        <property name="maxElementsInMemory" value="${cache.activity.maxMemoryElements}"/>
      </bean>

       <bean id="activityCacheService" parent="abstractService" class="com.service.business.cache.impl.ehcache.EHcacheActivityCacheService">
        <property name="cache"  ref="activityCache"/>
      </bean> 

      <bean id="classificationCache" parent="abstractOptionalCache">
        <property name="cacheManager" ref="cacheManager"/>
        <property name="maxElementsInMemory" value="${cache.classification.maxMemoryElements}"/>
        <property name="maxElementsOnDisk" value="${cache.classification.maxDiskElements}"/> 
        <property name="overflowToDisk" value="${cache.classification.useDisk}"/>
      </bean>

      <bean id="classificationCacheService" parent="abstractService" class="com.service.business.cache.impl.ehcache.EHcacheClassificationCacheService">
        <property name="cache"     ref="classificationCache" />
        <property name="enabled" value="${cache.classification.enable}"/>
      </bean>

        <bean id="userGroupCache" parent="abstractOptionalCache">
    <property name="cacheManager" ref="cacheManager"/>
    <property name="maxElementsInMemory" value="${cache.userGroup.maxMemoryElements}"/>
    <property name="maxElementsOnDisk" value="${cache.userGroup.maxDiskElements}"/> 
    <property name="overflowToDisk" value="${cache.userGroup.useDisk}"/>
  </bean>

  <bean id="userGroupCacheService" parent="abstractService" class="com.service.business.cache.impl.ehcache.EHcacheUserGroupCacheService">
    <property name="cache"     ref="userGroupCache" />
    <property name="enabled" value="${cache.userGroup.enable}"/>
  </bean>
```

I will provide more info upon your request.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you did all right, but just wrong at

```
rmiUrls=//localhost:40002/activityCache|//localhost:40002/userGroupCache|//localhost:40002/featureCache|//localhost:40002/classificationCache//localhost:40003/activityCache|//localhost:40003/userGroupCache|//localhost:40003/featureCache|//localhost:40003/classificationCache
```

you missed **`|`** between classification and activity cache

```
//localhost:40002/classificationCache//localhost:40003/activityCache
```

That's the reason both these caches weren't working!